# How to fetch SQL table data and loop through the multiple ID's

Tags: python, mysql, sql, loops

Need help on the below.
I have one SQL table which contains ID's and report date columns.
in an excel file i have all the list of ID's & report date for the respective ID.
Now i want to pull all the rows for each Id with the particular report date mentioned in excel file.

Can some one please help me on this how can i achieve this..

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So in essence what you are trying to build is an application that can connect to a SQL server and query data based on an input from an excel file.

**To read data from SQL:** 
Use sqlalchemy package for connecting to SQL (will work with most frequently used SQL server's) e.g. if the SQL is Microsoft SQL Server you would use pyodbc package to connect to it.
If you want to work with mysql you will not need an additional package.
[link](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/index.html#unified-tutorial) to official sqlalchemy tutorial

**To read / write data into excel** you can use pandas (a very popular package for data analysis and manipulation)
[link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/10min.html#min) to pandas documentation

An alternative is to use openpyxl package which is more lightweight.
[link](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to official doc.

These are the tools you need to build your app.
Try it out and then come back with a more specific question.